# Trying to create comments inside posts - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, simple-form, posts

I'm traying to create a social media with posts and comments inside the posts.
I'm trying to link the comments to the posts but I'm not going well. I dont know if the bug is from the controllers or the views. That`s what I have:

Comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end
```

routes:

```
resources :posts do
    member do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

posts controller (the idea is to show the comment form and show inside the posts, and make a kind of feed, like facebook, instagram.. ):

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.includes(:user).order(updated_at: :desc)
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    if @post.save
      redirect_to request.referrer
      # redirect_to feed_users_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :user)
  end
end
```

comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.post = @post
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to request.referrer
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post, :user)
  end
end
```

this is the post index:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="row"  id="post-<%= post.id %>">
      <div class="col-12 post-container">

        <!-- header -->
        <div class="post-header d-flex justify-content-start">
          <%= link_to user_path(post.user) do %>
            <h5><%= post.user.first_name  %> <%= post.user.last_name  %></h5>
          <% end %>
          <p>
            <%= link_to user_path(post.user) do %>
              @<%= post.user.first_name %>
            <% end %>
            <span><%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, post.created_at) %></span> ago
          </p>
        </div>

        <!-- content -->
        <div class="post-content">
          <div class="post-text">
            <h4><%= post.content %></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form--input">
          <%= simple_form_for([@post.comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
            <div class="form--input">
              <%= f.input :content, input_html: { class: "form-txt py-3" }, placeholder: "What do you want to comment?", label: false %>
            </div>
            <div class="form--input_elements d-flex justify-content-between mx-4">
              <div class="form--input_submit">
                <%= f.submit "Post Comment", class: "btn btn-flat", id: "post-submit", role: "status", remote: true %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the form for new comment which belongs to @post should be: `<%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true) do ...`

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the routes file, it should be like this :

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```